# Web Config Issue with IIS 7.5 MVC 5 App

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-7.5

So I have an MVC 5 application which has been running fine and is published to two individual servers, with the same configuration, however one gives http status 500, the other works perfectly. Both servers are exactly the same windows release, and patched up to asp.net 4.5.1.

Browsing the site locally gives the source of the problem as the web.config file, with the relevant config source lines being -1: and 0: Both showing blank lines.

I've no idea what's going on with this one. I have copied the app in its entirety back from the working instance to the none working instance no avail.

I'm a bit stumped.

[image: exception]

To note, i've also removed IIS and reinstalled as i thought that could be the cause of the issue.

Comment: Without knowing what the error says its hard to know whats going on but perhaps this would help: http://knowledge.3essentials.com/web-hosting/article/651/support.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after much headscratching it turns out that some clown removed URL Rewrite module from this box. After reinstalling using the web platform installer all is well. I hope somebody finds this useful in future.

Nicolas Carlo, your response pushed me down an alternate route of diagnosing the problem and was helpful in this instance, thank you.